# Jython - using Pygments in Java project

Tags: java, python, jython, pygments

I'm trying to use [Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/) in Java project by including Jython.jar. In my Java project I have `src/main/python` source directory where I placed pygments files into pygments folder so they end up on the classpath. Now I created highlighter.py file in the src/main/python with the following content:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('WEB-INF/classes')
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

class Highlighter:
    def colorize(code, lexername):
        lexer = get_lexer_by_name(lexername, stripall=True)
        formatter = HtmlFormatter(linenos=True, cssclass="source")
        return highlight(code, lexer, formatter)
```

Then I defined Java interface `Highlighter.java`

```
public interface Highlighter {
    String colorize(String rawText, String lexer);
}
```

And lastly I created factory class that uses `PythonInterpreter` to expose `highlighter.py` as a Jython object [as described here](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/September2006/1)

Now, when I run this line of code

```
Highlighter hl = (Highlighter) jf.getJythonObject(Highlighter.class.getName(), 
       "WEB-INF/classes/highlighter.py");
```

I get PyException as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "WEB-INF/classes/highlighter.py", line 3, in 
  from pygments import highlight
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
```

This occurs if I use Jython v. 2.5.0. In 2.1 I had to copy Jython/Lib directory under src/main/python but then I end up missing IOString module

Or maybe there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve? I'm curious if anyone was able to use Pygments in Java project.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions

Comment: What does `sys.path` contain?

Comment: Now when you mentioned it I have added sys.path.append('WEB-INF/classes') to highlighter.py. Testing

Comment: Now I have a different problem - I edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right. I figured it out. Made few beginner errors but if you are wondering how to make Pygments work in your Java project here's [full tutorial link](http://dev.bostone.us/2010/12/01/python-pygments-in-java-with-jython/)

Highlights:

- Using bare jython.jar is insufficient.
- Adding Jython/Lib to your classpath doesn't work. I ended up unjarring jython.jar and adding Lib directory + all pygments files to the resulting structure and then jarring it up again
- Factory example form the link above is convoluted. Much better way is to use Jython book [chapter 10](http://jythonpodcast.hostjava.net/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#using-jython-within-java-applications)
- For examples of changed highlighter.py, Highlighter.java and HighlighterFactory.java see the tutorial

Comment: And it performs like hell. Abandoned, but the tutorial is good for general setup of Jython in Java webapp

Comment: Hi, how was performance just for code snippets of 10-20 lines max?